# Selecting two highest values from a list, whilst keeping a record of their index positions?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, max

I am trying to get the highest and the second highest values from list a. I also need to keep track of what the index value was for each of these values.

For example:

```
a = [1,2,7,9,3,4]
```

Desired output:

```
maxVal = 9
secondMax = 7 

index_max = 3
index_secondMax = 2
```

Does any one have any suggestions for how to approach this, can't seem to figure out a way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sorted` and `list.index`:

```
MaxVal, secondMax = sorted(a)[-2:]
index_max = a.index(MaxVal)
index_secondMax = a.index(secondMax)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,7,9,3,4]
max_value = np.sort(a)[-1]
max_value2 = np.sort(a)[-2]
int(np.squeeze(np.where(a == max_value))),int(np.squeeze(np.where(a == max_value2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate` to pair the values with their indices, sort using the second value (the value, not it's index) and keep the last ones

```
from operator import itemgetter
a = [1,2,7,9,3,4]
res = list(sorted(enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1)))[-2:]

print(res) # [(2, 7), (3, 9)]
print("1st Max", res[-1][1], "at", res[-1][0])  # 1st Max 9 at 3
print("2nd Max", res[-2][1], "at", res[-2][0])  # 2nd Max 7 at 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution using sorted is cleanest, but for long lists this might be faster (linear complexity):

```
a = [1,2,7,9,3,4]
index_max, maxVal = max(enumerate(a), key=lambda x:x[1])
index_secondMax, secondMax =  max([t for t in enumerate(a) if t[0] != index_max],  key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is quite god for things like this

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,7,9,3,4]

b = np.sort([(v, i) for i, v in enumerate(a)])

maxVal = b[-1, 0]
index_max = b[-1, 1]

secondMax = b[-2, 0]
index_sec_max = b[-2, 1]

print(maxVal)
print(secondMax)

print(index_max)
print(index_sec_max)
```

Comment: This will give the wrong index position for `index_sec_max` if the second highest element comes after the first, since you shift the original list to the left by one element.

Comment: Fixed, your way is simpler though

Answer (score 1):

```
secondMax, Max  = sorted(a)[-2:]
index_max = a.index(Max)
index_secondMax = a.index(secondMax)
```